# RestSharp XML to Object

Tags: c#, xml, object, restsharp

I'm using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) to make a call to a web service. The service returns an XML file which I want to convert to a C# object.

The XML file looks this but contains multiple jobs:

```
 <jobs>

<job>
    <standard_fields>
        <start_date>2015-04-23</start_date>
        <end_date>2015-05-23</end_date>
        <title>Ad Titel</title>
        <reference>Test offer Dutch-9483599</reference>
        <job_description>...</job_description>
        <profile_description>...</profile_description>
        <company_description>...</company_description>
        <company_name>MLV Partners</company_name>
        <application_email>offre9483599.9252@mlvpartners.contactrh.com</application_email>
        <education_level id="6">Specialisatie</education_level>
        <work_experience id="6">4-5 jaar</work_experience>
        <contract_type id="2">Tijdelijk</contract_type>
        <location>...</location>
        <function id="20500">Informatiesystemen / telecommunicatie</function>
        <sub_function id="20518">Ingenieur Studies / Ontwikkeling</sub_function>
        <sector id="40000">Informatica / Telecommunicatie / Internet</sector>
        <sub_sector id="40002">Software-uitgever</sub_sector>
        <id>9483599</id>
    </standard_fields>
    <custom_fields>
        <recruiter_id>Recruiter ID</recruiter_id>
    </custom_fields>
</job>

<jobs>
```

While my C# class looks like this:

```
 public class job
    {
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "standard_fields")]
        public StandardFields standard_fields { get; set; }

        [DeserializeAs(Name = "custom_fields")]
        public CustomFields custom_fields { get; set; }
    }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "custom_fields")]
    public class CustomFields
    {
        public string recruiter_id { get; set; }
    }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "standard_fields")]
    public class StandardFields
    {
        public DateTime start_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime end_date { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string reference { get; set; }
        public string job_description { get; set; }
        public string profile_description { get; set; }
        public string company_description { get; set; }
        public string company_name { get; set; }
        public string application_email { get; set; }
        public string education_level { get; set; }
        public string work_experience { get; set; }
        public string contract_type { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string function { get; set; }
        public string sub_function { get; set; }
        public string sector { get; set; }
        public string sub_sector { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
```

I think that my C# class matches the XML structure.
So now, all I should have to do is call the API.

```
    var client = new RestClient("....");

    var request = new RestRequest("...");

    request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp =>
    {
        resp.ContentType = "application/json";
    };

    request.RootElement = "jobs";
    var listJob = client.Execute<List<job>>(request);

    Console.WriteLine(listJob.Data.ToString());
```

This doesn't work though , `listJob` is null and the RestSharp request gives the error message *Invalid JSON string*.

Could someone help me find a solution to this problem?

**EDIT**

Ok , I got my stupid error and removed this.

```
 request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp =>
    {
        resp.ContentType = "application/json";
    };
```

Now i'm trying to work with a list.

**FINAL EDIT**

Problem solved !

```
            var client = new RestClient("..."); 
            var request = new RestRequest("...");
            var listJob = client.Execute<List<job>>(request);

            foreach (var job in listJob.Data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(job.standard_fields.reference);
            }
```

Comment: You think that XML equals to JSON ?

Comment: Well they are not equal but it still bugs if I remove     request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp =>
    {
        resp.ContentType = "application/json";
    };

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace ConsoleApplication19
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\Test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            jobs jobList = new jobs(){
               jobList = new List<job>(){
                  new job() {
                   standard_fields = new StandardFields{
                       start_date = DateTime.Parse("2015-04-23"),
                       end_date = DateTime.Parse("2015-05-23"),
                       title = "Ad Titel",
                       reference = "Test offer Dutch-9483599",
                       job_description = "...",
                       profile_description = "...",
                       company_description = "...",
                       company_name = "MLV Partners",
                       application_email = "offre9483599.9252@mlvpartners.contactrh.com",
                       education_level = new CID() {id = 6, value = "Specialisatie"},
                       work_experience = new CID() {id = 6, value = "4-5 jaar"},
                       contract_type = new CID() {id = 2, value = "Tijdelijk"},
                       location = "...",
                       function = new CID() {id = 20500, value = "Informatiesystemen / telecommunicatie"},
                       sub_function = new CID() {id = 20518, value = "Ingenieur Studies / Ontwikkeling"},
                       sector = new CID() { id = 40000, value = "Informatica"},
                       sub_sector = new CID() { id = 40002, value = "Software-uitgever"},
                       id = 9483599
                   },
                   custom_fields = new CustomFields(){
                       recruiter_id = "Recruiter ID"
                   }
                   }

               }
           };

           XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(jobs));

           StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
           XmlSerializerNamespaces _ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
           //_ns.Add("", "");
           //serializer.Serialize(writer, icp, _ns);
           serializer.Serialize(writer, jobList);
           writer.Flush();
           writer.Close();
           writer.Dispose();

           XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(jobs));
           XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
           jobs  newJobs = (jobs)xs.Deserialize(reader);
                 
        }

    }
    [XmlRoot("jobs")]
    public class jobs
    {
        [XmlElement("job")]
        public List<job> jobList { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("job")]
    public class job
    {
        [XmlElement("standard_fields")]
        public StandardFields standard_fields { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("custom_fields")]
        public CustomFields custom_fields { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("custom_fields")]
    public class CustomFields
    {
        public string recruiter_id { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("standard_fields")]
    public class StandardFields
    {
        [XmlElement("start_date")]
        public DateTime start_date { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("end_date")]
        public DateTime end_date { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("title")]
        public string title { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("reference")]
        public string reference { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("job_description")]
        public string job_description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("profile_description")]
        public string profile_description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("company_description")]
        public string company_description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("company_name")]
        public string company_name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("application_email")]
        public string application_email { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("education_level")]
        public CID education_level { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("work_experience")]
        public CID work_experience { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("contract_type")]
        public CID contract_type { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("location")]
        public string location { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("function")]
        public CID function { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("sub_function")]
        public CID sub_function { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("sector")]
        public CID sector { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("sub_sector")]
        public CID sub_sector { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("id")]
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
    public class CID
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string value { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public int id { get; set; }
    }


  
}
```

Comment: Well that was not my post. I'm actually looking it. Thanks, but It doesnt really help me :)